# How can I call a scope function inside a controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call a scope function inside the controller. My aim is to call the function in the load itself.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.functionname();

    $scope.functionname = function() {}
});
```

Comment: Do this ` $scope.functionname = function() {}; $scope.functionname();`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call the function in controller.

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    functionname();

    function functionname {
       //do something.
    }
});
```

> If you are looking to reuse the function outside controller then use Service as controllers are not injectable.

Answer (score 0):

Read johnpapa style guide which shows best practices: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function(someService) {
    var vm = this;

    activate();

    function activate() {
       // Do something.. You can get the data from your service 
    }
});
```

Then do your `$http` in services then inject it in your controller/s.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use services:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.service('SomeService', ['$state', function ($state) {
        this.someFunction = function() {
          return "some value";
        };
}]);


app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http, SomeService) {
  SomeService.someFunction();
});
```